# Migrating from STM32

Tags: stm32, arm, hal-library

Our company spent couple years streamlining development and porting everything from a mess of different platforms to one unified STM32-based architecture. And now with global chip shortage it came back to haunt us.

A search for devices with similar periphery set returned just a few chips from Renesas, Cypress and NXP, and even that supply seems to be running dry. There also were some much larger chips from Microchip and others. If this situation does not improve I'll be forced to redesign for different chip soon, and I only worked with PIC, Atmel and STM before.

The question then is - what platform would be least painful to migrate to from STM32? (specifically F3, L4 and G4 series)

The core business logic should be portable, of course. So I am asking mostly about HAL-level compatibility or portability. If anyone has an experience with ARM chips from other manufacturers I would really appreciate an advice.

UPDATE:

Just to give an example of what I am asking about: In our UART library for STM32 we are using DMA and circular buffers to avoid data loss at high bandwidth. We also using IDLE interrupt to deal with variable length packets. If either of these features is not supported by the hardware and/or framework then migration will be unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Isn't this either opinion-based or product recommendation question?

Comment: (1) Use Microchip. The last time a huge shortage occurred, they didn't only cater to their high volume customers but instead made sure that the suffering was shared by all. I was able to get parts and I don't buy many at all and some of my customers are low-volume, 1-5k part purchasers too and were treated well. They didn't own Atmel then. Atmel was an exact opposite experience. (2) Put into place a plan for an eventual move to RISC V as options become available. It's where the energy is going, I think. (3) Use Microchip. ;) Yup. Entirely opinion, devoid of any knowledge of your circumstances.

Comment: @Justme I would argue it is neither. It is a question of framework capabilities from different manufacturers. I am not asking you to choose a product for me, nor am I asking "which product is better in your opinion". I am simply seeking an advice from people who worked with different platforms and have actual migration experience. Please, see an update in the question.

Comment: @jonk So far whatever I read about RISK-V boils down to excited "it is open source!!!". Which is hardly a technical reason for a switch. I do like latest RISK-V chips from ESP32 though. The flexibility provided by their pin multiplexing is awesome. But their framework is way to different from STM in the context of this question, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't have a good answer but I sure feel your pain.

Comment: @mkeith you know... that is surprisingly helpful :)